# how to hide the border of <img> tag (when the img load error)

Tags: html, css

while there is no "src" attribute in the  tag or the "src" linked to a resource which dose not existed,there'll display a border out of the  tag.
just like this
//html code:

```
<div class="example" style="height:70px;width:100px">
<img src="404error.html">
</div>
```

[image]

//↑↑↑ in firefox

[image]

//↑↑↑ in chrome

// css code

```
.example img{
display:inline-block
height:30px;
margin:20px;
}
```

how can I hide this border // border:none; is useless

besides,there is another stange phenomenon.
 That is,when I set "line-height" to a  tag,the border of img which i said will move down,so it looks not around the picture at all.
and it just appear in chrome,but not in firefox.
like this.

[image]

//↑↑↑ in firefox

[image]

//↑↑↑ in chrome

//css code

```
.example img{
display:inline-block
height:30px;
margin:20px;
line-height:70px; //this is the difference
}
```

p.s. i use the "line-height" just for the words not the imgs.when i set .img{line-height:0;}it returns.i just want to know why.and how to hide the border.
thanks.

Comment: Put the image to display:block.  Inline-block has line-height.  Block has no line height.

Comment: i've tried but it seems not effective

Comment: Can you use something like: `img[src =''], img[src = '404error.html'] {border:none;}`?

Comment: i means the attribute "border" can't control this kind of border at all.it not depends on the selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/s3Lvr9bs/1/

```
<div class="example">
    <object data="https://developers.google.com/+/images/branding/button-gplus.png" type="image/jpg">
    <img src="404error.html" alt="" />
    </object>
</div>


.example {
 display:inline-block;
 background:#444;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 padding:5px;
 min-width:30px; min-height:30px;
}
object {display:block;}
```

You need:

- img alt="" (hides in Firefox)
- object data (gets the url for image)
- object display block, to remove margins.